# Panel Visibility via JS

Tags: javascript, ajaxcontroltoolkit

The tutorial at http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/getting-started/creating-a-custom-ajax-control-toolkit-control-extender-vb gives a nice example of a custom extender based on a textbox and a button. Basically the button remains disabled until at least one character is typed into the textbox. If the text is removed from the textbox the button is disabled again.

I am trying to modify this so that the extender is based on a textbox and panel. Again I want the panel to become visible when text is present in a textbox.

This is how I amended code...

```
Type.registerNamespace('CustomExtenders');
CustomExtenders.ShowHidePanelBehavior = function (element) {
    CustomExtenders.ShowHidePanelBehavior.initializeBase(this, [element]);
    this._targetPanelIDValue = null;
} 

CustomExtenders.ShowHidePanelBehavior.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {
        CustomExtenders.ShowHidePanelBehavior.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');

        // Initalization code 
        $addHandler(this.get_element(), 'keyup',
        Function.createDelegate(this, this._onkeyup));
        this._onkeyup();
    },

    dispose: function () {
        // Cleanup code  

        CustomExtenders.ShowHidePanelBehavior.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
    },

    // Property accessors  
    // 
    get_TargetPanelID: function () {
        return this._targetPanelIDValue;
    },

    set_TargetPanelID: function (value) {
        this._targetPanelIDValue = value;
    },

    _onkeyup: function () {

       var e = $get(this._targetPanelIDValue);
        if (e) {
            var visibility = ("" == this.get_element().style.value);
            e.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }

}

CustomExtenders.ShowHidePanelBehavior.registerClass('CustomExtenders.ShowHidePanelBehavior', Sys.Extended.UI.BehaviorBase);
```

When run the panel will not appear. No errors are produced.

Where have I gone wrong...

Comment: Do you initializing `CustomExtenders.ShowHidePanelBehavior` object with client or server id of the target panel? Show the GetScriptDescriptors method of control to clarify that. By the way, you must unsubscribe from the keyup event in `dispose` method and delete delegate created with Function.createDelegate method. Otherwise you'll got a memory leak on client.

Comment: Thanks Yurij, the above is just the JScript part of the solution. As in the Asp.net example there are two more files which I can post if necessary. The two vb files basically collect and tie up the controls specified in the parameters when using the controlextender. I'm sure I have a problem with my _onkeyup function but can't put my finger on it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
_onkeyup: function () {
    var panel = $get(this.get_TargetPanelID());
    if (panel) {
        var visibilityValue = ("" == this.get_element().value) ? "hidden" : "visible";
        panel.style.visibility = visibilityValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pryvit Yurij, shchyro Djakuju!... I like to understand code, and as my forte is VB and not javascript could you explain what the line var visibilityValue = ("" == this.get_element().value) ? "hidden" : "visible"; does. I will test in the morning an let you know if it works.

Comment: Привіт Юрій! Все чудово працює. Дуже дякую. Михайло

Comment: If anyone is interested I've made several extenders that link the following to a textbox - Panel, DropDownList, Secondary TextBox. In each case the target control remains disabled or hidden until text is entered in the initial TextBox. I can share the code.